# How to write a Regular expression to match any non alphabet or number and also matching dot

Tags: java, regex

I need to match any special character in a string. For example, if the string has & % € (), etc. I could have Unicode alphabets such as ä ö å.

But I also want to match a dot "." For example, if I have a string as "8x8 Inc." . It should return true. Because it has a .

I tried a few expression so far but none of them worked for me. Please let me how it can be done? Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you please show us some correct and non correct inputs? and also please share the expression you already tried

Comment: What about `[\W\.]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that one:

`[^a-zA-Z\d\s]`  -> basically anything outside the group of all a-Z characters, digits and spaces. It will capture all other characters including special letters ä, dots, commas, braces etc

A simpler version would be  `[^\w\s]` and it would match any non word/space characters but it will not match ä ö å

Comment: or just `\W` which matches all except word characters

Comment: yeah but with \W he will match spaces too which as I understand he doesn't want

Comment: *expression to match any non alphabet or number and also matching dot*. I guess that is interpretation dependant, but yes. If spaces should not be possible, then your version works

Comment: yep sorry  I interpreted it like that - like getting special characters. If we match space then \W would be the best (simplest) solution

Answer (score 0):

Java Regex **.*** will match all characters.
If you want to match only dot(.) then use escape character like **\.** It will match only dot(.) in string.
And in Java Program you have to use it like.

```
 String regex="\\.";
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Unicode character classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). For your example, I think something like `"(\\p{IsAlphabetic}|\\d)+"` should work